# Security with dynamically generated sql query

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, search

I'm creating a sidebarsearch(by clicking options), and picking the variables clicked to create sql query.

More specifically: 
1. user selects options in sidebar.
2. I create str(as url to be called) based on those selections adding params as 'param1=value&'...
3. ajax call to php controller->model->query dababase based on params via $_GET.

I use the prepared statements in the end but in theory the attacker can make up their own url. To avoid this i pre specify the allowed values($keysArr) and if $_GET vars are not there the script dies. Also simply adding int() to expected numeric values, so php will trow and error if it's not int.

```
$keysArr = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

foreach ($ArrfromGET as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, $keysArr)) {
        die("don't attack me");
    }
}
```

Am i doing this correctly ? 
The search is based on values generated dynamically so i'm not sure what to do about it. The code is based on(https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_database.asp);

Comment: You can use @parameter query

Comment: Iv never seen it before, how is the concept called ? I need to read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Note I'm just showing how to secured dynamic query in SQL

```
DECLARE @ParameterDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX) 
 SET @ParameterDefinition = '  
  @P_Name NVARCHAR(50)  
 , @P_Address NVARCHAR(50)';
DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Name  NVARCHAR(50) = '' //set here value
DECLARE @Address NVARCHAR(50) = '' //set here value

SET  @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM USER WHERE Name = @P_Name OR Address = @P_Address'
 
 
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParameterDefinition,
 @P_Name = @Name,
 @P_Address = @Address
```

Comment: Iv never seen it before, how is the concept called ? I need to read more about it.

Comment: Please read more details here click on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: This nothing but parameters passing inside the query and we set the value when our store procedure called, here we passing actually value and avoided `SQL injection`