# Are there problems with SQL side white listing for Dynamic SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have an application where I want to produce historical charts from our database.
These charts can be many different parameters that are stored in our table, with a coupled datetime.

The stored procedure would contain something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLog]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @getIdEntity INT = 0 ,
    @columnName VARCHAR(100),
    @startDate DATETIME2,
    @endDate DATETIME2

AS
    SELECT logs.[DateTime], 
        logs.@column1 as Property
        from dbo.LogTable logs
    WHERE logs.[IdEntity] = @IdEntity AND logs.[DateTime] >= @startDate
    AND logs.[DateTime] <= @endDate 
    AND logs.column1 IS NOT NULL;'
```

This does not work, inserting a column as a parameter is not possible.

The answer was, of course, dynamic SQL, which obviously leads to a SQL injection problem.

the procedure then becomes:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLog]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @getIdEntity INT = 0 ,
    @columnName VARCHAR(100),
    @startDate DATETIME2,
    @endDate DATETIME2

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here



    DECLARE 
    @dynamicSql NVARCHAR(500),
    @timespan INT

    SET @dynamicSql = '
        SELECT [DateTime],  
        [' +@columnName+'] as Property from dbo.EntityTransactionLogEntry etl 
        WHERE etl.[IdEntity] = '+ CAST(@getIdEntity AS VARCHAR(10))
        + ' AND etl.[DateTime] >= '''+ (CONVERT (VARCHAR(50),@startDate,121)) +''''
        + ' AND etl.[DateTime] <= '''+ (CONVERT (VARCHAR(50),@endDate,121)) +''''
        + ' AND etl.[' +@columnName+'] IS NOT NULL;
    EXEC (@dynamicSql)'
```

Which is obviously still vulnerable to SQL inject.

Is simply adding:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EntityTransactionLogEntry'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = @columnName)
BEGIN
    PRINT  'Bad Input'
    RETURN
END
```

(I also limit maximum time span that is query-able, but I'm not worried about that here)
before the Dynamic SQL portion sufficient to protect this from injection? 
It is designed to fail in an invalid column name is supplied.

If yes, then presumably creating a view with only column names I approve of querying would be allowed to limit the columns that can be used?

I am specifically worried about injection, but I think I am safe, this will only be available from our API.

Comment: Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543198/security-with-dynamically-generated-sql-query/58543345#58543345

Comment: I tried to make use of sp_executesql, however I  still couldn't change columns dynamically. A select * is not an option, it affects performance too much. I am also fairly sure that I would not be able to check the column for null values either, which has an even greater impact on performance.

Comment: I'm just showing how we secured our dynamic query in SQL, or prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I realize that, however in this specific application the reason for not using sp_executesql is that it does not provide the functionality I require. I specifically need the dynamic column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is simply adding [a check in INFORMATION_SCHEMA] before the Dynamic SQL portion sufficient to protect this from injection?

By definition, no. What's happening is still SQL injection.

What you're asking, technically, is whether it's safe from *malicious* SQL injection.

Your checking INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a reasonable protection. It's a form of *whitelisting*, which is the technique we must use for things that can't be replaced by query parameters.

If there were a column in `EntityTransactionLogEntry` whose name could "break" the delimited identifier syntax, you'd be in trouble, but I assume you have control over the column names in your own table, and you wouldn't do that.

You should restrict your INFORMATION_SCHEMA query to your own TABLE_SCHEMA. As your query is currently written, it would be satisfied if *any* table catalogued in I_S has that column name.

Also, I'm not sure why you are not using query parameters in your terms for IdEntity and DateTime, where the values *can* be replaced by query parameters. You should do that.

Comment: I like the distinction you make between SQL injection and malicious injection, it makes for a subtle point, however I am satisfied if I only allow safe queries to be formed.

I will update the query to make use of TABLE_SCHEMA, although I surmise nothing prevents me from making a table with a genuine whitelist.

Fortunately I largely have control over the DB, so I know there are no malicious column names.

In terms of the IdEntity and DateTime, these are parameterised from my API side, so I am less worries, but I will also make the addition.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Flippie

Tipically you can do some like

```
parameters..
.. paramterx varchar(100) = null,
paramtery varchar(100) = null

select *
from entitytransactionlog
where
  logs.[IdEntity] = @IdEntity AND logs.[DateTime] >= @startDate
  AND logs.[DateTime] <= @endDate 
  and (columnvalue = parameterx or parameterx is null)
  and (columnvalue2 = parametery or parametery is null)
```

so sp is invoked like

```
exec sp parameterx = 'value'
```

the validation "OR" in bracket let every values if value in parameter is not defined